# MySQL Query - Join Subquery

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

**What I have**

I have multiple Tables like this:

> - tbl_hw_inventar (hw_id, hostname, hw_typ_idfs, hw_created_user_idfs, etc...)
> - tbl_hw_typ (hw_typ_id, hw_typ_title, etc...)
> - tbl_user (user_id,username, etc...)
> - tbl_hw_edited (hw_edited_id, hw_edited_client_idfs, hw_edited_date, hw_edited_user_idfs)

**What I need**

I want output a table with the following information:

```
 hw_id | Hostname | created                         | last edited 

 12315 | client-01 | 2015-05-06 15:31:06 (username) | 2015-07-02 09:46:17 (username) |
```

**The problem**

As you can see, I can get information like the hw_typ with a **foreign key** and a **inner join** to the "`tbl_hw_typ`". The same for information with "`hw_created_user_idfs`" and a inner join to get the **username** for the **userid**.

But how can I get the **last edited**, **datetime** and the **username**?

In my table "`tbl_hw_edited`" i have entries like this:

```
row id | hw_id | datetime | user_id
```

**The code**

My SQL query looks like this so far:

```
SELECT `tbl_hw_inventar`.*, `tbl_hw_typ`.`hw_typ_title`, `tbl_user`.`username`, `tbl_hw_edited`.`hw_edited_id` 
FROM `tbl_hw_inventar` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_hw_typ` 
ON `tbl_hw_inventar`.`hw_typ_idfs` = `tbl_hw_typ`.`hw_typ_id` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_user` 
on `tbl_hw_inventar`.`hw_create_user_idfs` = `tbl_user`.`id`
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(`tbl_hw_edited`.`hw_edited_id`), `tbl_hw_edited`.`hw_edited_client_idfs`
    FROM `tbl_hw_edited`
    ) `tbl_hw_edited` ON `tbl_hw_inventar`.`hw_id` = `tbl_hw_edited`.`hw_edited_client_idfs`
ORDER BY `tbl_hw_inventar`.`hw_id` ASC
```

So how can I export the information? It looks like I have to make a subquery in my query. But I failed with every try.

**Thanks for you help**

**EDIT**

As proposed I'm providing more information (table data) for each table:

```
-tbl_hw_inventar-
| hw_id | hw_hostname | hw_create_date      | hw_create_user_idfs |
| 1     | client-01   | 2015-03-06 11:57:42 | 1                   |
| 2     | client-02   | 2015-09-21 21:17:00 | 3                   |

-tbl_hw_edited-
| hw_edited_id | hw_edited_client_idfs | hw_edited_date      | hw_edited_user_idfs |
| 1            | 1                     | 2015-09-24 17:30:22 | 1                   |
| 2            | 2                     | 2015-09-24 16:33:22 | 2                   |
| 3            | 1                     | 2015-09-24 23:30:22 | 2                   |
| 4            | 2                     | 2015-09-24 20:30:22 | 3                   |

-tbl_user-
| id | username |
| 1  | ismaelw  |
| 2  | skalb    |
| 3  | yrumpel  |
```

So as a final result I need an output like this:

```
| hw_id | hostname  | created                       | edited                      |
| 1     | client-01 | 2015-03-06 11:57:42 (ismaelw) | 2015-09-24 23:30:22 (skalb) |
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if there were a few rows of data for each table. Having sample data removes some guesswork and allows us to test our suggestions.

Comment: where do you get the created date from?

Comment: @Used_By_Already I added a few more details about what I need and some rows of table data.

Comment: yes, got the data thanks, & I see you have the created date, just add that into the select clause where you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have interpreted your tables correctly, you need to find the max(edit date) for each hw_edited_client_idfs (which joins to hw_id)

```
                            SELECT
                                  hw_edited_client_idfs
                                , MAX(hw_edited_date) AS last_edit_dt
                            FROM tbl_hw_edited
                            GROUP BY hw_edited_client_idfs
```

With that result you may join it back to the source table, to discover which user is associated to the max(edit date)

```
                SELECT
                      het.*
                FROM tbl_hw_edited AS het
                      INNER JOIN (
                            SELECT
                                  hw_edited_client_idfs
                                , MAX(hw_edited_date) AS last_edit_dt
                            FROM tbl_hw_edited
                            GROUP BY hw_edited_client_idfs
                      ) AS mx ON het.hw_edited_client_idfs = mx.hw_edited_client_idfs
                                  AND het.hw_edited_date = mx.last_edit_dt
```

Then this result used like so:

```
SELECT
      i.hw_id
    , i.hw_hostname
    , uc.username created_by
    , he.hw_edited_date last_edit_date
    , ue.username last_edit_by
FROM tbl_hw_inventar AS i
      INNER JOIN tbl_user AS uc ON i.hw_create_user_idfs = uc.id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT
                      het.*
                FROM tbl_hw_edited AS het
                      INNER JOIN (
                            SELECT
                                  hw_edited_client_idfs
                                , MAX(hw_edited_date) AS last_edit_dt
                            FROM tbl_hw_edited
                            GROUP BY hw_edited_client_idfs
                      ) AS mx ON het.hw_edited_client_idfs = mx.hw_edited_client_idfs
                                  AND het.hw_edited_date = mx.last_edit_dt
          ) AS he ON i.hw_id = he.hw_edited_client_idfs
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_user AS ue ON he.hw_edited_user_idfs = ue.id
```

which produces this result:

```
| hw_id | hw_hostname | username |              hw_edited_date | username |
|-------|-------------|----------|-----------------------------|----------|
|     1 |   client-01 |  ismaelw | September, 24 2015 23:30:22 |    skalb |
|     2 |   client-02 |  yrumpel | September, 24 2015 20:30:22 |  yrumpel |
```

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbce7/1)

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm!